# jQuery selector selecting all rows... why?

Tags: jquery

I have a standard HTML table that looks something like this in structure:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>FOOTER</td>
      <td>
          ... other td columns
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>some other row that I don't want selected</td>
      <td>
          ... other td columns
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

What I would like to do is select only the tr's that contain the text FOOTER in a td, and then set the font-weight to bold for all td's under the selected tr's. My problem is that the jQuery selector I have is setting all td's within the table to bold and I'm not sure why.

Here's my selector thus far:

```
$("tr:contains('FOOTER')").children("td").css("font-weight", "bold");
```

Comment: Works fine here - http://jsfiddle.net/WkHLP/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps your table is nested inside another. So the `tr:contains()` will match the parent `tr` of the whole table, and then proceed to find the `td` and set them to `bold`..

<strike>Perhaps</strike>

```
$("td:contains('FOOTER')").siblings().css("font-weight", "bold");
```

would be a better candidate (*scrap that idea as it would do the same by applying the bold at a higher `td`*)

Comment: Thank you! That was it. I refined my selector to include the table id and it works as expected now.